# Download file contents and names into a List with Apache Camel FTP

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I would like to download a list of files with name and content in Apache Camel.

Currently I am downloading the file content of all files as byte[] and storing them in a List. I then read the list using a ConsumerTemplate.
This works well. This is my Route:

```
        from(downloadUri)
            .aggregate(AggregationStrategies.flexible(byte[].class).accumulateInCollection(
                    LinkedList.class))
            .constant(true)
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .to("direct:" + this.destinationObjectId);
```

I get the List of all downloaded file contents as byte[] as desired.

I would like to extend it now so that it downloads the content and the file name of each file. It shall be stored in a pair object:

```
public class NameContentPair {

    private String fileName;
    private byte[] fileContent;

    public NameContentPair(String fileName, byte[] fileContent) { ... }
}
```

These pair objects for each downloaded file shall in turn be stored in a List. How can I change or extend my Route to do this?

I tried Camel Converters, but was not able to build them properly into my Route. I always got the Route setup wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing a custom AggregationStrategy.

It reads the file name and the file content from each Exchange and puts them into a list as a NameContentPair objects. The file content and file name is present in the Exchange's body as a RemoteFile and is read from there.

The general aggregation implementation is based on the example implementation from https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html

The aggregation strategy is then added to the route

```
        from(downloadUri)
            .aggregate(new FileContentWithFileNameInListAggregationStrategy())
            .constant(true)
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .to("direct:" + this.destinationObjectId);
```